# Calling WCF service over node proxy works on localhost only

Tags: node.js, proxy, wcf-data-services, ntlm, node-http-proxy

I am trying to call a WCF Data service on another domain. The service uses NTLM, and the JSON returned depends on the authenticated user. I am using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to get over cross domain issues.
The service, lets say

> http://**otherdomain:1234**/dataservice.svc/getData

returns a JSON like

```
    {
        "description": "xxxxx",   
        "data": {
            "subclass": [
                [
                    {
                        "name": "xxxxx",
                        "keys": {     
                        },
                        "children": "xx"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "parameter": "someparam",
        "option": {
              "someoption": []
            }
     }
```

For users with no data configured, it just returns an empty JSON skeleton like

```
    {
        "description": "",   
        "data": {},
        "parameter": "",
        "option": {}
     }
```

In my proxy server I have set `target` as http://otherdomain:1234 and call the service as

> http://**localhost:8003**/dataservice.svc/getData

from my client application. This works perfectly fine(from application and browser directly). NTLM authentication is working; no CORS issue. I am getting the JSON like the first example.

But when I call the proxy using my IP address instead, like so

> http://**10.203.147.21:8003**/dataservice.svc/getData

I get the empty JSON skeleton only, no other errors. What is happening here? Working with localhost but not IP.

Interestingly, this happens with the actual service as well; i.e. if I use the IP address of the data server (called directly from browser) instead of the name, I get a similar empty JSON.

> http://**10.203.147.34:1234**/dataservice.svc/getData

Could someone explain what is going on here? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `changeOrigin` to `true` in the `options` object of `httpProxy` has fixed the issue. Now the proxy is able to negotiate NTLM from different domain properly.
Guess the server was returning empty response for requests from different origin.